# JPA OneToOne and shared primary key need manual assignment

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Springboot and JPA to create two tables sharing the same primary key.

For the first table I write:

```
public class UserAccount implements Serializable
 {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
   @OneToOne(mappedBy ="user", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE, 
                                         CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
   private UserLogin login;
 }
```

For the second table I write:

```
public class UserLogin implements Serializable
  {
    @Id
    private Long user_id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, 
               fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @MapsId("user_id")
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
   private UserAccount user;
   public void setUser(UserAccount user)
    {
     this.user = user;
     this.user_id = user.getId();    
    }
  }
```

Other stuff are omitted for conciseness. The code works because I manually set the id of UserLogin by writing the statement

```
this.user_id = user.getId();
```

otherwise I get the error:

> Hibernate error: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():

I guess that the ids can be manually managed but I cannot get the right configuration.

UPDATE:
I found the solution thanks (see the accepted answer). Now I just would get rid of the findById() when setting the user login.

```
//these methods are defined within a dedicated @Service
@Transactional
public void createLoginInfo(UserAccount user)
{
 UserLogin userlogin=new UserLogin();       
 this.addLoginToUser(userlogin,user);
 loginService.save(userlogin);
}

@Transactional
public void addLoginToUser(UserLogin login, UserAccount account)
{
  //whit this commented line works
  //UserAccount acc= this.findById(account.getId());   
  login.setUser(account);      
  account.setLogin(login);
}

//In a transactional test method I first create the user then I call
userService.save(theuser);
userService.createLoginInfo(theuser);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
public class UserLogin implements Serializable
  {
    @Id
    private Long user_id;

   @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @MapsId
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private UserAccount user;

   public UserAccount getUser() {
     return user;
   }
   public void setUser(UserAccount user) {
     this.user = user;
   }
  }

public class UserAccount implements Serializable
 {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
 }
```

To persist UserLogin :

```
EntityManager em;
UserAccount user = em.find(UserAccount.class, 1L)
UserLogin login = new UserLogin();
login.setUser(user);
em.persist(login);
```

Comment: Your solution seems working. Do you know why I cannot use:
setLogin(UserLogin login, UserAccount account){ login.setUser(user)}

even all the methods are transactional?

Comment: I don't know. May be you should show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bidirectional relationship, but have mapped it with a few competing options that don't work well together. First, in UserAccount, it isn't clear why you have an ID that is generated, yet try to also map it with the relationship (specifically using a PrimaryKeyJoinColumn). If you want it generated, it can't also be a foreign key value in a reference - and you've already got this relationship setup as the 'other' side via the 'mappedBy' setting. It should just be:

```
public class UserAccount implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
   @OneToOne(mappedBy ="user", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE, 
                                         CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   private UserLogin login;
 }
```

User login then should just be:

```
public class UserLogin implements Serializable {
   @Id
   private Long user_id;
   @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, 
               fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @MapsId("user_id")
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
   private UserAccount user;
   public void setUser(UserAccount user) {
     this.user = user;   
   }
}
```

Note because you have the mapsId annotation on the user relationship, JPA will set the user_id property for you once the ID is assigned - there is no need to manually set it yourself. You can, but if you do you must insure it was assigned previously - which requires a save/flush on the UserAccount. If you don't actually use the Long user_id property, you don't really even need to map it; you can just mark the user property as the ID:

```
public class UserLogin implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, 
               fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
   private UserAccount user;
   public void setUser(UserAccount user) {
     this.user = user;   
   }
}
```

The Long ID from UserAccount then can be used to lookup UesrAccounts and UserLogin instances.

Comment: I removed @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn from UserAccount and removed the manual assignment of the Id in UserLogin but I get the error reported in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I ment "detached error".

Comment: What detached error exactly? Detached means you are taking an existing entity - likely an UserAccount instance you've read from a different context/transaction and associated it to your UserLogin. Either mark the login->User relationship with cascade settings (risky) or be sure to read it in using the same transaction you are using to save the userLogin instance.

Comment: The error is given when I use setUser even when I use the same transaction that creates the UserAccount.

Comment: What error? what code? You'll need to show how you use these objects as that is the problem now, not the mappings.